# Plot png file encoded as string without saving to file

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, io

I am using a library function that returns a png image as string.
This string can be written to a file like this:

```
    img_string = png_print_formatter(weblogoData, weblogoFormat)
    f = file('test.png', 'w')
    f.write(img_string)
    f.close()
```

And it can also be read by matplotlib, for instance via the plt.imread() function.
However, I would like to convert the string to a format, that I can use to display the image directly (without having to save to a file).
I know that plt.imread() reads a file in binary mode.

Google suggested me the encode() function of strings but no luck there:

```
    img_string.encode('utf-8')
    ...
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this? I am no expert on these things but I am sure there is a solution for it.

Thank you very much and best regards,

Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use StringIO:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

img_string = png_print_formatter(weblogoData, weblogoFormat)
fake_file = StringIO(img_string)
plt.imread(fake_file)
```

The code above is for python 2. In python 3 the StringIO is the the `io`module and you should probaby use `BytesIO` class instead of the `StringIO` class.